# The Yoneda embedding induces a monad-like structure?

Tags: ct.category-theory

This question was already [asked on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2802500/the-yoneda-embedding-induces-a-monad-like-structure).

---

In CAT the Yoneda embedding $C^{\text{op}} \stackrel{y_C}{\to} \text{hom}(C, \text{Set})$, induces a map $$\text{hom}(\text{hom}(C, \text{Set}), \text{Set}) \stackrel{y^*_C}{\to} \text{hom}(C^{\text{op}}, \text{Set})$$

Thus, if we call $T = \text{hom}(\_, \text{Set})$.
We have a map (which is not even dinatural): $$\_^{\text{op}} \stackrel{\iota}{\to} T$$ and a kind of multiplication,

$$T^2 \stackrel{\mu}{\to} T \circ \_^{\text{op}}. $$

Is there a way to say that $T$ is *contravariant monad* on CAT?! I looked online for such a notion and I did not find anything.

---

Note, even if $\iota$ is not dinatural, i.e. $f^*y_Hf \neq y_G$, for a functor $G \stackrel{f}{\to} H$, looking at CAT as a 2-category, there is a $2$-cell $$y_G \Rightarrow f^*y_Hf.$$

What does it mean? If we look at the presheaf construction as a kind of power set the map $y_G \Rightarrow f^*y_Hf$ is witnessing that $\{a\} \subset f^{-1}\{f(a)\}$ for a function $f: A \to B$ between sets and an element $a \in A$.

Another way to say it is that the $2$-cell is $y_G \Rightarrow f^*y_Hf$ is individuated by the universal property of $f^* \cong \text{Lan}_{y_Hf}(y_G)$.

Comment: It might be instructive to look at the "toy" example of posets first. There it amounts to maps $P^\circ\to{\uparrow}(P)$ (all upper sets of $P$) given by $x\mapsto[x)$ (principal upper set of $x$) and ${\uparrow}({\uparrow}(P))\to{\downarrow}(P)$ given by $\mathscr U\mapsto\{x\mid[x)\in\mathscr U\}$. It is thus a meet-completion of sorts: any order preserving map $f:P^\circ\to M$ to a complete meet-semilattice $M$ extends to a meet-preserving map $\hat f:{\uparrow}P\to M$ via $\hat f(U)=\bigwedge f(U)$

Comment: Of course your are right. Maybe I have not been clear, I was wondering if such a notion already exist in literature and if this *monadic behavior* of hom$( \_  , \text{Set})$. was already observed.

Comment: It seems to me that you are just observing the monadicity of $C \mapsto (T(C^{op}))^{op}$ ? up to size question, this is the "free completion" monad.

Comment: But is *monad*, even *weak $2$-monad* the correct word? It is not covariant.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti: it's *both* covariant and contravariant, since it takes every functor to an adjunction; see the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/functoriality+of+categories+of+presheaves). The power set functor on $\mathsf{Set}$ behaves in the same way: in comes in a covariant and a contravariant version, for which the reason secretly is that it takes every map of sets to a Galois connection.

Comment: @TobiasFritz I think something different is meant by non-covariance, namely, that it involves "transformations" between functors of different variances

Comment: There are a lot of intertwined issues here, but regarding what kind of transformation your $\iota$ is, you might check out https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-dinatural+transformation .

Comment: If you specifically want this contravariant yoneda monad, I'm not sure what you do, but with the covariant yoneda embedding $y : C \to  [C^{op},\mathrm{Set}] $ , you do get a monad (I'm pretty sure - haven't checked the equations). Uncurry to get $[[C^{op},\mathrm{Set}]^{op},\mathrm{Set}] \times C^{op} \to \mathrm{Set}$ which is given by $1 \times y^{coop} ; ev$ where $y^{coop} : C^{op} \to [C^{op},\mathrm{Set}]^{op}$ is the op of the contravariant yoneda embedding, and $ev : [A , B] \times A \to B$ is evaluation. (con't)

Comment: Profunctors $B^{op} \times A \to \mathrm{Set}$ are equivalently functors $A \to \hat B$ with composition given by $F;_{Prof} G := F; Lan_y(G)$ where $Lan_y(G)$ is the left Kan extension of G along the yoneda embedding. This should (again, I haven't yet checked) be the kliesli composition for this monad.